# How can I uninstall the Intel C++ Compiler (ICC) 11 on Vista x64?

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, uninstallation, intel, icc

I installed the combined package of ICC 11.0.066 for x86 & x64 targets, with all options (IPP, TBB, MKL). Attempting to run the uninstaller from Control Panel > Programs and Features immediately errors out with the dialog:

> Another instance of uninstall was launched.
>   Please wait while it is finished ...

This happens after having also uninstalled VTune (successfully), but does not resolve itself after reboots, etc.

How is it possible to force the Intel Compiler to uninstall and clean up after itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downloadable installers for Intel software development tools extract their install packages by default into:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Download
```

It is possible to re-run

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Download\C++CompilerPro11.0\Setup.exe
```

manually. This will include both Repair and Uninstall options, both of which should complete successfully. If the extracted setup files are not still intact, it should be possible to recreate them by re-running the downloaded installer package for the same version.